# jQuery Validate plugin dynamically choose error element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and I would like to be able to dynamically determine the `errorElement` based on the type of element that has an error. I know that you can the `errorElement` like so:

```
$("form").validate({
    errorElement: "div"
});
```

However, I would like to be able to change it so that if the type were a checkbox or radio button, then I could make the `errorElement` an `li`. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm looking at [the code in the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js) and the `errorElement` option is simply looking for an element as its parameter.  Since there is no callback function for `errorElement`, I see no direct way to achieve what you ask without modifying the plugin itself.

Maybe you could do something with the `errorPlacement` callback instead.

Let's say just leave it as a `label` and then wrap it with some other container?  Or use `errorElement` to put them all inside a `<span>`, while using `errorPlacement` to `wrap` them dynamically in whatever container.  See [jQuery `.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var type = $(element).attr("type");
        if (type === "radio") {
            // custom placement
            error.insertAfter(element).wrap('<li/>');
        } else if (type === "checkbox") {
            // custom placement
            error.insertAfter(element).wrap('<li/>');
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element).wrap('<div/>');
        }
    },
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/uLH4f/**